# Unknown Type Name 'CMStepCounter'

Tags: objective-c, import, core-motion, healthkit

I'm trying to count the steps of user using `CoreMotion`, `HealthKit`and everything that is needed.
At first I tried it with Swift (I'm not good with swift) and imported these two files:

```
import HealthKit   
import CoreMotion
```

And when I declared `CMStepCounter` it successfully declared it, means the type was found. Here is how I declared it:

```
let stepCounter:CMStepCounter = CMStepCounter()
```

Moving on I got stuck and decided to shift to objective c and started writing the same code in objective c style. But when I declared it:

```
CMStepCounter *_stepCounter;
```

It gave me the error `Unknown Type Name 'CMStepCounter'`.
This is because I haven't imported `CoreMotion` & `HealthKit`while working with objective C. So how can I import those two written above in swift to objective c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import the HealthKit and CoreMotion frameworks in an Objective-C file, add the following to the top of the file:

```
#import <HealthKit/HealthKit.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
```